# How to make a procedural texture from multiple images?

Tags: texturing, image, texture-coordinates, random

I have several images of ceramic tiles, square shape. I need to fill the surface with them so that they lay down randomly, and not I manually arranged them individually.

Comment: I never used UDIM tiles, but maybe that can be used.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would put them into a single texture into a grid of unique tiles and then use math to manipulate texture coordinates and noise textures for randomisation:

[image]

You could also use the same principle, to scale them by -1 in both axis or rotate.

[image]

And that's a more complete node group with mirroring and rotation and also white noise nodes for better randomness:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Really great node setup!

Comment: It's just amazing! Thank you very much for the decision!

Comment: @Akinetsu, If that's useful consider upvoting or accepting as the answer.

Answer (score 8):

This method is pretty much the same as [Martynas'](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/294564/35559).. I thought it was going to be lazy, avoiding the math by using a non-random *Voronoi* to do the grid.

- It subtracts the 'Position' of the Voronoi from the overall texture space to get UV-per-cell
- It uses the R & G of the (random) 'Color' output, with a stepped *Map Range*, to select a tile from the array of tiles provided in the *Image* texture.
- It uses the B of the 'Color', also stepped, to rotate the tiles randomly per cell

[image]

There's also a parallel 'Distance to Edge' Voronoi being run, in case that's useful.

The group can be used something like this..

[image]

.. for this kind of result:

[image]

I don't think it's as lazy as I hoped.. it doesn't actually save that many nodes..

[image]

Comment: It's just amazing! Thank you very much for the decision!